# Raffle between different groups composed by different numbers

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random

I've got this issue, I need to prepare a raffle between teams for a cars race.
Cars are grouped by teams. Rounds are 1:1, composed by different manches until the cars are done. Total number of cars is even 
The problem is that I'd like to reduce as more as possible the number of rounds between same team cars and also to make an equal probability that these could happen in each teams.
The number on cars in each team could vary from 2 to 8, these would include also odd number of cars and odd number of teams.
In not very good at math but I thought something like this:

- Start the first random choices between groups with the higher number of cars, until the all have reach the lowest number of cars in a team

Le's suppose that I have 5 Teams: the first composed by 8 cars, 2nd 3 cars, 3rd 5 cars, 4th 4cars, 5th 4 cars.
The lowest number is 3, so I start to raffle between the higher until they reach the next level.

- 1st Team with 3rd -> 7 and 4
- 1st Team with 3rd -> 6 and 3
- 1st Team with 4th -> 5 and 3
- 1st team with 5th -> 4 and 3
- 1st Team with 2nd -> 3 and 2
- 1st team with 3rd -> 2 and 2
- 4th team with 5th -> 2 and 2
- 1st team with 2nd -> 1 and 1
- 3rd with 4th -> 1 and 1
- 5th with 1st -> 1 and 0
- 2nd with 3rd -> 0 and 0
- 4th with 5th -> 0 and 0

  Do you think is an "equal" way of doing random picks?